# Can FFMPEG library send the live H264 iOS Camera stream to Wowza using RTSP

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, rtsp, wowza, live555

My requirement is to get iphone camera feed, encode it into H264 format and send it to server.
In search, I found encoding part is possible with ffmpeg lib with x264 (libx264). But now the next task is to send the encoded data to Wowza server using rtsp.

Please share some code or useful document if anyone is aware about this.

There is one another library for encoding purpose live555. But I am not sure it can send the data to server using rtsp.

Answer (score 4):

Actualy I made an iOS streaming app (with wowza as streaming server)

I believe you can stream video only with FFmpeg with rtsp protocol although FFmpeg don't fully support it

However with ffmpeg you can get a valid SDP and pass it to wowza using RTCP protocol - ANNOUNCE OPTION SETUP RECORD -

I didn't use FFmpeg for encoding but if you can get the raw H264 data you can packetize it to make a valid RTP packet using [rfc6184](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6184)

edit :
here is a sample to connect wowza :

```
    NSString* response = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ANNOUNCE %@ RTSP/1.0\r\n",self->addr];
    response = [response stringByAppendingFormat:@"CSeq: %d\r\n",self->cseq];
    response = [response stringByAppendingFormat:@"Content-Type: application/sdp\r\nContent-Length: %d\r\n\r\n", [self->sdp length] ];
    response = [response stringByAppendingString:self->sdp];
    NSString* result = [self sendAndRecvData:response];
```

where sendAndRecvData is a tcp socket bound to wowza_ip:1935

you can use the same kind of code for SETUP, which will send back RTP (+RTCP) ports where you should send your datas

Comment: Can you describe bit more how to create connection with wowza server and create the packets kind of stuff. With FFMPEG it is very hard to find the functions and sequence to calling functions. It is really messed up.

Comment: you can find an rtp packetizer in libavformat/rtpenc.c source. For the wowza connection part, you can begin with a static sdp file in the /content directory, and look for RTCP announce protocol. I'm still a beginer so my code is very messy, I reversed Wirecast protocol to make it works

Comment: sry for double post : here is [my related wowza post on their forum](http://www.wowza.com/forums/showthread.php?29806-RTP-RTSP-streaming-is-there-a-way-to-transmit-sdp)

Comment: Hane, I am facing problem to understand how to create packets, and send the data to server. I have even compile various other libraries like live555 and cURL but again stuck at initial point how to proceed.

Comment: Do you mean video rtp packets ?

Comment: yes, how to create packets from encoded data and how to send these to wowza server using rtsp.

Comment: [rfc 3984](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3984.txt) may helps you to create a h264 rtp packetizer. All you need is to create a 12 bytes header for your encoded data and send it to wowza (udp). FFmpeg should give you an SDP file that you need to put in wowza content folder. According to your SDP file, Wowza will listen specified ports. Your project is not an easy one and if you begin with RTSP protocol you can read "RTP Audio and Video for the internet" by Colin Perkins.

Comment: Hane, do you have any idea about rtsp tunneling over http. I understood this point as we can send the data to server http post by sending first the options, describe, setup formats of rtsp into http body. Please correct me on this.

Comment: I don't know much about this, I believe [spydroid](https://code.google.com/p/spydroid-ipcamera/) is using http tunneling. I will edit my 1st answer

Comment: Hi Hane, As per your code snippet in the above thread, I am able to send the initial commands to wowza and getting the RTSP OK responses. Now my next job is to send the encoded video data to wowza. For this I am creating two udp socket connection with ports which I am getting in  SETUP response. I am sending directly video data in udp socket. Can you tell me, if there is any specific udp packet structure in which I need to send the data. Write Now I am facing error :  WARN server comment - RTPDePacketizerBase.checkRTCPSSRC: ssrc error: 0:2e345555

Comment: hi, as I said you should read rfc 3984 and "RTP Audio and Video for the internet" by Colin Perkins

Comment: Thanks Hane I first go through this document and then come back to you

Comment: Hane, I gone through the rfc3984 doc, but it is very hard to think and understand this in programming paradigm. But I found "Geraint Davies" blog http://www.gdcl.co.uk/2013/02/20/iOS-Video-Encoding.html where he has provided sample code with H264 encoding and NALU classes. Now I uses these class to send the packet to wowza but still I am facing error RTPDePacketizerBase.checkRTCPSSRC: ssrc error: 0:2e345555. Does such kind of error is due to bad packet creation or something else..

Comment: I don't know how do you make your packets, the error seems to be related to your ssrc field. Is it the same in rtp packets and rtcp ones ?

Comment: value to ssrc variable is initialize as : _ssrc = random();

Comment: Correction in above comment 
value to ssrc variable is initialize as :                       _ssrc = random() 
and in header packet we write _ssrc as :
tonet_long(packet + 8, _ssrc)
and in rtcp packet tonet_long(buf+4, _ssrc)

Comment: Hi Hane,  <br/>
I am getting some logs on wowza as  <br/>
RTSPRequestAdapter.getAuthenticationHandler: Unknown method: 0  <br/>
RTSPRequestAdapter.service: Unknown method: unknown  <br/>

Answer (score 1):

Your using live555 , you can use a live 555 server living on the device to send both audio and video, this will give you rtsp+rtcp stream to wowza, for announce and record live 555 has an unsupported dss module.

Comment: can you provide some code snippet for that or some document which describe the classes and functions needs to be used to make connection, and stream publishing

Comment: Michelle, I compiled the live555, But when I used it in XCode project then it start giving errors. Code is not able to unnderstand c++ class types. Can you tell me about the settings I need to do when I use live555 for iOS.

Comment: if you contact me directly I can help you, but it will take much more time then I have this minute, sorry

Answer (score 0):

Wowza has an iPhone app called GoCoder which will send a live encoded stream to a Wowza server.

Comment: can we send the iphone live camera stream to wowza using http live streaming and for this what kind of settings we need to do on server side.

Answer (score 0):

You can stream directly to a Wowza server using RTMP instead of RTSP. The ffmpeg command is something like:

```
ffmpeg -re -i localFile.mp4 -c copy -f flv rtmp://server/live/streamName
```

As long as you specify your output format as flv and the output destination as rtmp://xxx then you should be OK.

Source:
[ffmpeg streaming](http://sonnati.wordpress.com/2011/08/30/ffmpeg-%E2%80%93-the-swiss-army-knife-of-internet-streaming-%E2%80%93-part-iv/)

Comment: how to use a camera feed instead of a local file to stream to a RTMP url